# Is there a known predecessor for Jenny Sparks?

Tags: comics, wildstorm-comics

Jenny Sparks is a character created by Warren Ellis that first appeared in the Stormwatch comics and then lead The Authority. She is a *century child*, an embodiment of the 20th century. Her successor is Jenny Quantum, an embodiment of the 21st century.

Is there any known predecessor for Sparks or any other known *century children*?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jenny_Sparks

Comment: http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Category:Century_Babies

Comment: I actually checked wikipedia's entries for Sparks and Quantum. Quantum's century children entry links to Sparks, so I got nothing from it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jenny Steam appears in the 12 part series "[The Authority : Revolution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Authority#Revolution)". She is described as being '***The Spirit of the 19th Century***'.

Since Jenny Sparks is 'The Spirit of the 20th Century', we can reasonably assume that this was her direct predecessor, in the same way that her death heralded the birth of Jenny Quantum; 'The Spirit of the 21st Century".

**Jenny Steam**
[image: Jenny Steam]

- Her other predecessors (many of whom lived substantially longer than 100 years) include Jenny Revolution, Jenny Crusade, Jenny Inquisition, Jenny Plague, Jenny Ra, Jenny Fire and Jenny Stone.
- Other "[Century Babies](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Category:Century_Babies)" include Jenny Fractal, Gaia Rothstein, River Baldwin, Elijah Snow, Dr Axel Brass, etc.

Comment: Wasn't Bret Leather, another of the Century Babies?

Comment: @Monty129 - There's a bunch more on that link. I've not posted an exhaustive list.

Comment: Ah, gotcha.  It's been awhile since I've read any Planetary, but now seems as good a time as any to pick up the trades again.